# What is the "center of the robot" in costmap_2d's footprint?

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap-2d, footprint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [robot setup navigation tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup), it says:

"In the case of specifying the footprint, the **center of the robot** is assumed to be at (0.0, 0.0)..."

From this, it sounds like they want it to be the actual center of the robot, but then how does it relate this to the center of rotation, which is used everywhere else?  Because in my case, I have static transforms that relate the sensor positions to the center of rotation, not the actual center of the robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217646/what-is-the-%22center-of-the-robot%22-in-costmap_2d%27s-footprint?/) by [kwiesz91](https://answers.ros.org/users/23432/kwiesz91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2015-09-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-09-15**:
what is "everywhere else" where they refer to the center of rotation?

**Comment by [kwiesz91](https://answers.ros.org/users/23432/kwiesz91/) on 2015-09-15**:
I should have just said: "...but then how does this relate to the base_link"

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-09-15**:
alright ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As they say

> In the **case of specifying the footprint**, the center of the robot is assumed to be at (0.0, 0.0)...

This means, when you specify the footprint, you have to specify the endpoints relative to where **YOU** put the center (and this means, the `base_link`) of the robot. It does not need to be the actual center. This depends on your robot, application and base kinematics.

E.g., there are some common locations you put the `base_link` of the robot, that depend on the kinematics. For omnidirectional robots, most people have it as the physical center of the robot. For differential drive robots, it usually is the middle of the axis of the two driven wheels, independently of the physical dimensions of the robot.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwiesz91](https://answers.ros.org/users/23432/kwiesz91/) on 2015-09-15**:
Thank you so much.  This is the exact answer i was looking for.  Maybe I'm crazy in thinking that the text could be a little clearer?  Or maybe it can just blatantly say "the center is where you have your base_link" for people like me.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-09-15**:
Well, having this as `base_link` is also just a convention.
Actually, for the costmaps, you have the parameter `robot_base_frame` which could be set to something else.

**Comment by [kwiesz91](https://answers.ros.org/users/23432/kwiesz91/) on 2015-09-15**:
I figured, but good point.